# Is it possible to list everything a specific process is trying to do?

Tags: linux, java, profiling, jboss

I have a web app in a jboss application server that gives a not understandable error.

I’m 100% sure it is because it is trying to access a forbidden file system location.
Is it possible to profile the program, in particular what is doing step by step (ex. Spawning processes, opening files, writing files, etc)

Comment: try jboss logs, `lsof` (to get list of files process is accessing) and https://jbossprofiler.jboss.org/

Comment: Or you can use `strace` if you really want low-level info.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `strace`, also consider `sysdig`.  Sysdig is somewhat like a system-wide version of `strace`.  You can find more information at [Sysdig's Github Page](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/)

Answer (score 1):

For the type of investigation that you outline (independent of language), `strace` is your friend. It will tell you what system call are happening. By default it does not trace across `fork`, but you can enable it.